# Interpolation to less denser grid + Least-squares fitting in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, interpolation, least-squares

I am new in Python and a bit confused with the **interpolation** and **Least-squares fitting of two ndarrays**.

I have 2 ndarrays:

[image: ndarrays]

My *final goal* is to make Least-squares fitting of the modelled spectrum (blue curve) to the observed spectrum (orange curve).

Blue curve ndarray has the following parameters:

[image]

Orange curve ndarray has the following parameters:

[image]

As a first and the easiest step I wanted to plot the residuals (difference) between that two ndarrays, but the problem is that since they have different sizes 391 and 256 respectively. I've tried to use `numpy.reshape` or `ndarray.resphape` functions, but they lead to an errors.

Probably the proper solution will be to start with the interpolation of the blue curve into the less denser grid of the orange curve. I've tried to use `numpy.interp` function but it also leads to an errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_denser = 33
n_coarser = 7

x_denser = np.linspace(0,1,n_denser)
y_denser = np.power(x_denser, 2) + np.random.randn(n_denser)/10.

x_coarser = np.linspace(0,1,n_coarser)
y_coarser = np.power(x_coarser, 2) + np.random.randn(n_coarser)/10. + 0.5

y_dense_interp = np.interp(x_coarser, x_denser, y_denser)

plt.plot(x_denser, y_denser, 'b+-')
plt.plot(x_coarser, y_coarser, 'ro:')
plt.plot(x_coarser, y_dense_interp, 'go')

plt.legend(['dense data', 'coarse data', 'interp data'])
plt.show()
```

Which returns something like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion seems to stem from mixing up the methods you mention. Least-squares is *not* a method for interpolation, rather it is a minimization curve fitting method. One key difference is that with interpolation the plots always pass through the original data points. With least-squares this can happen bit it is not generally the case.

Cubic-spline interpolation will give you 'nice' plots if you need to pass through the original data points.

If you want to use least-squares, you need to know what degree polynomial you want to fit. The most common is linear (first order).